# Send and read serial commands from terminal

Tags: shell, minicom

I have a very limited list of software that I can install on an (IOT edge) device. I have `minicom` and `chat` commands (in addition to standard commands like `echo` and `cat`), and need to write to a serial device a command and read the response.

The device in question is a modem, and I need to run AT commands on it. If using `minicom` and setting up the menu etc. I can run these commands normally, and get the output. The problem is that I have around a thousand of these devices, so setup and data logging needs to be automated.

So within these parameters is there a way to run `minicom` and capture the output without any interactive elements? I have tried

```
minicom -S scriptfile -C outfile
```

where scriptfile (for now) contains following:

```
sleep 1
send "AT"
```

This seems to ignore the `sleep` command, and *outfile* is created, but is left empty. Also what would I need to add to the command that it wouldn't open a session or interactive element?

Comment: If your system does indeed have [the powerful `expect` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), then its options are not "very limited".

Comment: I'm not sure it actually has expect, as the script does not run, or even obey the command sleep. The limitation is that I cannot install almost anything on the boxes, as they are in a private network, and I don't have control over the repo. It was a pain to get even openssl on the box.

Comment: What happens when you run `expect -c 'send "hello world\r"'` on the system in question?

Comment: It prints:    `-ash: expect: not found`

Comment: Apparently the system in question does not have `expect`.  Please modify the question to remove all mentions of `expect`.

Comment: Typically `chat` as in `man 8 chat` is used to automate talking to a modem.

Answer (score 0):

> So within these parameters is there a way to run minicom and capture the output without any interactive elements?

I am not sure about minicom, but I have a better tool for this job which was written specifically for the purpose to being able to run AT commands non-interactive from the command line with capture capabilities: [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/).

You can automate this in any way you like, for instance

```bash
for device in mydevice0001 mydevice0002 ... mydevice1000
do
    atinout my_at_commands.txt /dev/$device capture-$device.txt
done
```